# mvn liquibase:diff command does not generate contexts and What is createSequence changeSet, why it is generated?

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, maven, liquibase

I'm using maven liquibase and on running the mvn liquibase:diff -Plocal, the generated diff changelog is not having a context tag in changeSets.

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.1.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.1.xsd">
<changeSet author="testUser (generated)" id="1603187434414-1">
    <createSequence cycle="false" incrementBy="1" maxValue="9223372036854775807" minValue="-9223372036854775808" sequenceName="orderconsumer_shipment_id" startValue="1"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="testUser (generated)" id="1603187434414-2">
    <createSequence cycle="false" incrementBy="1" maxValue="9223372036854775807" minValue="-9223372036854775808" sequenceName="orderlineroutingjobs_jobnumber_seq" startValue="1"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="testUser (generated)" id="1603187434414-3">
    <createSequence cycle="false" incrementBy="1" maxValue="9223372036854775807" minValue="-9223372036854775808" sequenceName="revision_sequence" startValue="1"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="testUser (generated)" id="1603187434414-4">
    <addColumn tableName="fulfillment_container_details_audit_3">
        <column name="container_number_3" type="varchar(255 BYTE)"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

What is createSequence changeSet, why it is generated?

Note: application-local.properties is my property file, I have added property spring.liquibase.contexts=local and I'm using it against SQL SERVER/MSSQL

Comment: Why do you expect to have a context from a generated diff changelog?  As for the sequences, they should be there if they exist on the local db, so does orderconsumer_shipment_id for example exist in the db?

Comment: Here I don't want add container_number_3 column in fulfillment_container_details_audit_3 in another context...